# Concealed vs hiding

Tags: word-usage

Conceal is a synonym of hide. 
 We write, "he stood there in hiding"  without mentioning hidden behind what.
 In the same way, can we write, "he stood there concealed" without explicitly mentioning concealed in or by what?

Answer (score 2):

> We write, "he stood there in hiding" without mentioning hidden behind what.

That is incorrect. When we say that someone is "in hiding" it means that they are evading capture or discovery over a period of time.

*John is in hiding. The police have been searching for him for ten days.*

---

If we wish to talk about a temporary circumstance, we might say:

*John is hiding*

or

*John is hidden* (from view)

---

Comment: Whatever you say is true when you say "John is in hiding"; however, when you say "John stood there in hiding" it means John is standing there, hiding from the view of someone.

Comment: "At the moment when her husband had interrupted the reading, she had drawn back behind the bed head, out of his sight. Supporting herself against the wall, she stood there in hiding, her eyes fastened in hungering suspense on the manuscript in Mr. Neal's hand." This is from Armadale by Wilkie Collins.

Comment: The first sentence tells the reader what she was hiding behind, so doesn't that answer your question? It doesn't have to be specified again.